# Kendo Grid drag & drop not working properly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jsfiddle

I have a Kendo grid [implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/76sLggyL/10/) with drag and drop.  When the selection mode is set to multiple rows...the drag and drop doesn't really work in Internet Explorer, though it works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
selectable: "multiple row"
```

So what happens in IE, is that when I try to drag a row, it selects multiple rows.  The `dragstart` event doesn't even fire.

The only way IE will do drag and drop is for me to select a row, go into Edit mode on the cell and then start dragging.

Is there something else special I have to do for Internet Explorer?  Or does Kendo Grid not work well with it?

Comment: I am having this exact same problem.  Have you figured out a way to fix it?

Comment: Same here. Any solution out there?

Comment: [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/4/)